# If Else with Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone please help me with the following scenarios I want to use with if/else conditions. I'm using java with Testng Eclipse.

1) If login is successful and navigates you to Home page, avoid try/catch
2) If login fails, go to try block.

```
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).submit();

      try{

        Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='errorMsg']")).getText().matches("Username or password incorrect. Try again."));
        }
        catch(Throwable t){
            Assert.fail("Username Or Password is Incorrect.");
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, title,"Home is not accessible!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be as simple as replacing the `try-catch` with an `if`, but since `findBy` will throw exception if no element is found, you have at least the following 2 approaches

1) create a reusable `findElementIfPresent` method which returns null if no element is found:

```
    private WebElement findElementIfPresent(WebDriver driver, By by){
        try {
            return driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...

    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).submit();

    // obtain the div which holds the information
    WebElement errorDiv = findElementIfPresent(driver, By.xpath("//div[@class='errorMsg']"));


    // if the div exists and it has an authentication-problem messages, fail
    if(errorDiv != null && errorDiv.getText().matches("Username or password incorrect. Try again."))
        fail("Username Or Password is Incorrect.");
    }

    // otherwise proceed with additional verifications
    assertEquals(actualTitle, title,"Home is not accessible!");
```

2) go with the [javadoc's suggestion](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) and use `findElements(By)` which returns a list of elements. In your particular case, if the list is empty then the authentication was successful, otherwise fail the test

```
    // obtain the list of error divs
    List<WebElement> errorDivs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='errorMsg']"));

    // if there is at east one element present
    if(!errorDivs.isEmpty()){
        // pick first one and use as main failure reason
        fail(errorDivs.get(0).getText());
    }

    // otherwise proceed with additional verifications
    assertEquals(actualTitle, title,"Home is not accessible!");
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Grove. Your code looks perfect, but the problem is that By.xpath("//div[@class='errorMsg'] which is carrying text '"Username or password incorrect. Try again." is not always there on login page and only comes out when user is failed to login. So for correct logins, webdriver is unable to locate this element. Actually, I'm using excel to use many users at the same time, so some has correct login details and some incorrect.

Comment: You are correct, `findElementIfPresent` will throw an exception if no element is found. Please see updated response

Comment: Great!! thank you so much, it's working for my scenario. But, if I want to add messages in report along with Fail(errorDivs.get(0).getText()); is it possible? It will make the report easy to understand by people who do not know much about coding. Currently, I'm just using index.html (TestNG) to see results.

Comment: Take a look at http://reportng.uncommons.org/ and see if it fits your need or you could even build your own report. Otherwise that would have to be another SO question.

Comment: Thanks, Grove. It helped me. Now I'm trying to generate report using ReportNG, but I will create a new question for it. :)